# How to cancel a particular task by timeout when using ThreadPoolExecutor in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using ThreadPoolExecutor in Java to parallelize items processing. Each item processing is a separate task, that I put it in a queue for the executor to process. Unfortunately, some tasks can take too long and I want to be able to cancel such tasks and continue with the rest. I don't want to wait for shutdown method and its timeout (overall processing takes days).
I want something like looping over currently executed tasks and checking for how long it is running and cancel it if it is above the limit.

Comment: You can use `FutureTask<Void>` to wrap your `Runnable`. It has `cancel()` method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ThreadPoolExecutor will return Future objects to you when you submit tasks to it.

Use the [get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method on your futures, and if you get TimeoutException, then call cancel on them.

Comment: Note that if you call `cancel(true)`, the code in your `Runnable` will throw an `InterruptedException` when any method that potentially throws it gets called, e.g., `sleep()`. You can also check if your thread is being interrupted by calling `Thread.interrupted()` as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html).

Comment: Let me add that if you do not call `Thread.interrupted()` or `sleep()` or whatever, your code will __not__ terminate just because it is part of a task that has been canceled.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta I agree. I did not go into details of task interruption because it is another topic.